# There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'primaryTypeID

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to learn MVC and I have been trying to mess around with it, this was working fine until I changed the model structure a little and got this error which I couldn't get rid of,

I tried changing the "primaryTypeID" into different values but it all gives the same error,

What is causing this error?

> There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that
>   has the key 'primaryTypeID'

Model:

```
public class inventoryModel
{
    public int inventoryNo { get; set; }
    public string inventoryName { get; set; }

    public int typeID { get; set; }
    public string typeName { get; set; }

    public int primaryTypeID { get; set; }
    public int secondaryTypeID { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> primaryTypeList { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> secondaryTypeList { get; set; }
}
```

The primaryTypeList:

```
Models.inventoryModel InventoryModel = new Models.inventoryModel();
InventoryModel.primaryTypeList = new SelectList(list, "typeID", "typeName");
InventoryModel.secondaryTypeList = new SelectList(list, "typeID", "typeName");
ViewBag.primaryTypeList = InventoryModel.primaryTypeList;
ViewBag.secondaryTypeList = InventoryModel.secondaryTypeList;
```

Razor:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("addInventory", "Admin", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div class="form-style-2-heading">Add New Inventory</div>
        <label>
            <span>Inventory No <span class="required">*</span></span>@Html.TextBox("InventoryNo", null, new { @class = "input-field" })
        </label>
        <label>
            <span>Name <span class="required">*</span></span>@Html.TextBox("InventoryName", null, new { @class = "input-field" })
        </label>
        <label>
            //Error is here
            <span>Primary Type <span class="required">*</span></span>@Html.DropDownList("primaryTypeID", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.primaryTypeList, new { @class = "select-field" })
        </label>
        <label>
            <span>Secondary Type <span class="required">*</span></span>@Html.DropDownList("secondaryTypeID", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.secondaryTypeList, new { @class = "select-field" })
        </label>

        <label><span>&nbsp;</span><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></label>

        @Html.TextBox("lbltest", ViewBag.test as string)
}
```

Comment: It means that `SelectList` is `null` (probably because you did not reassign it in the POST method when you returned the view). But why in the world are you using `ViewBag` when you already have the `SelectList` in the view model. Just use `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.primaryTypeID, Model.primaryTypeList, ...)` so you strongly bind to your model

Comment: @StephenMuecke Oops, I added condition preventing the reinitiate line, also can I ask you, do I have to do a query to reinitiate everytime I run a method? What is the best way to save the state of the model?

Comment: Do you mean to run the queries to generate the `SelectList`'s? Then yes.